Error Building iOS App on iPhone from Xcode: Missing Developer App Certificate
I'm trying to run a local iOS app on my iPhone via Xcode, but I encounter an error instructing me to trust the Developer App certificate. The exact message is:
"Open Settings on the device and navigate to General -> VPN & Device Management, then select your Developer App certificate to trust it."
However, I cannot find any Developer App certificate listed under VPN & Device Management in my device settings. I've tried reinstalling Xcode, but the issue persists. How can I resolve this and successfully build the app on my iPhone?



I think this is a Provisioning Profile issue.  What sort of app are you writing?

This app was just for testing push notification

When I disabled "Automatically manage signing" and explicitly choose Provisioning Profile, it worked.

Create a provisioning profile in App Connect. Check "Enable offline" (lasts for 7 days). Download the provisioning profile. "Import provisioning profile" in XCode, and choose that file.
